Negative lookahead not working as intended
I would like to create a regex, that matches along the following criteria and I am using the Select-String function of PowerShell. I have this query,and I want to get all parameter variations(so the part starting with @PAR) between a certain part of a query, where the #KEINERW part is not present.The issue is, when I test it in regex101 or if I run my script(same result), the #KEINERW version is matched as well, which it shouldn't.
This is the relevant query part:
INSERT INTO #BASIS_VARIABLEN
        select ''tagid'' as ParameterTyp,IdentCode as Variable 
        from R34_META_DELIVERY.zeit.Tag t
        where 1=1 '+dbo.SVF_GetAuswahlEinschraenkung('t.IdentCode',@PAR_MONAT_Stichtag)+'
        
        INSERT INTO #BASIS_VARIABLEN
        select ''bankid'' as ParameterTyp,BLZ as Variable 
        from R34_ZDW.orga.Bank t
        where 1=1 '+dbo.SVF_GetAuswahlEinschraenkung('t.BLZ',@PAR_BLZ)

        INSERT INTO #BASIS_VARIABLEN
        select ''segmentid'' as ParameterTyp,Segment as Variable 
        from R34_ZDW.orga.Bank t
        where 1=1 '+dbo.SVF_GetAuswahlEinschraenkung('t.Segment',@PAR#KEINERW_SEG_Segment)  

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

And I would like to get back only this part:
INSERT INTO #BASIS_VARIABLEN
        select ''tagid'' as ParameterTyp,IdentCode as Variable 
        from R34_META_DELIVERY.zeit.Tag t
        where 1=1 '+dbo.SVF_GetAuswahlEinschraenkung('t.IdentCode',@PAR_MONAT_Stichtag)+'

        INSERT INTO #BASIS_VARIABLEN
        select ''bankid'' as ParameterTyp,BLZ as Variable 
        from R34_ZDW.orga.Bank t
        where 1=1 '+dbo.SVF_GetAuswahlEinschraenkung('t.BLZ',@PAR_BLZ)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

It won't exlude the part:
INSERT INTO #BASIS_VARIABLEN
        select ''segmentid'' as ParameterTyp,Segment as Variable 
        from R34_ZDW.orga.Bank t
        where 1=1 '+dbo.SVF_GetAuswahlEinschraenkung('t.Segment',@PAR#KEINERW_SEG_Segment)

This is my script I have created, any ideas how to fix it to get the right result? The most important thing is, I have to use regex and less programming logic, hence my difficulty, I could solve it with -raw and indexes, but the regex should be reusablke with other languages. Here is my full PSScript:
$OutputFile = "C:\Users\WRSKOI\Documents\Check_USP_VW\outfile.txt"
$ErrorFile = "C:\Users\WRSKOI\Documents\Check_USP_VW\errorfile.txt"

# Create or overwrite the output and error files
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $OutputFile -Force | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $ErrorFile -Force | Out-Null

# Define the regex pattern to match the parameters (with multiline support using '(?s)')
$RegexPattern = "(?s)INSERT\sINTO\s#BASIS_VARIABLEN.*?@PAR_(?!#KEINERW)(?:TAG|MONAT|DATUM|DATUMVONBIS|BLZ|SEG|BER|GES|MAR|SPR|KSG|KST|REF|TEXT|KTO|TEXTAREA)[\w-]*.*?EXEC\s+sp_executesql\s+@sql"

# Get all .txt files in the specified directory (recursively)
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\WRSKOI\Documents\Check_USP_VW\TestUSP" -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    
    try {
        $File = $_.FullName

        # Read the entire file as a single string for multiline regex matching
        $FileContent = Get-Content -Path $File -Raw

        # Use Select-String to match multiline pattern in the content
        $Matches = [regex]::Matches($FileContent, $RegexPattern)

        # If any matches are found, write them to the output file
        if ($Matches) {
            foreach ($Match in $Matches) {
                $LineNumber = ($FileContent.Substring(0, $Match.Index).Split("`n").Count) # Calculate line number
                $Output = "File: $File, Line: $LineNumber, Match: $($Match.Value)"
                Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $Output
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        # Log any exceptions to the error file
        $_.Exception.Message | Add-Content -Path $ErrorFile
    }
}


Capture what you need, then concatenate. You can't get discontinuous text parts into a single string buffer with a regex match operation.

@Wiktor Stribiżew But the PAR_whatever part is continous, only the part before that and the ending is dsicontinious, but I don't need those in the match anyway, they are there to determine the location where it should match with the PAR part. Plus I use the Get-Content with -raw. Would it help if I share the whole script?

@Wiktor Stribiżew Done, thanks for the advice. :)
